# Javascript Dynamically inserted DOM Element automatically triggers onclick Event

Tags: javascript

I have been working an a auto-completion feature for a project that I am working on.
I want the user to be able to click on on of the auto-completions which will query more information about the product.
When assigning a onclick event to that dynamic created DOM element said onclick event automatically triggers.

Now I have reproduced this "error" in a js fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/50y4ma8h/2/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="results">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var resultsElement = document.getElementById("results");
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.append("Hey");
div.onclick = querySomething();

resultsElement.innerHTML = div.outerHTML;

function querySomething() {
    alert("hey");
}
```

I do not understand why the function that is assigned to the oncllick event is automatically called.

I would appreciate any Help :)

Comment: Right, remove that bracket `()` which means "execute me" function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div.onclick = querySomething();`

Is assigning the **result** of `querySomething` function to the handler, and not the function itself.

You probably meant:

`div.onclick = querySomething;`

Also note that moving the innerHTML somewhere else will not bring the bound onclick listener with it, so `resultsElement` will not have this event attached.

Comment: I see, thanks. But now when clicking the div nothing happens :/

Comment: right answser here. @istepaniuk, could you prupose also using `addEventListener` which are the prefered way to bind click event.

Comment: @LostSoul, I updated my answer. You have to attach the event to the `resultsElement` instead, or append your new div to the parent instead of transfering the inner HTML.

Comment: Instead of using innerHtml property I appended the DOM elements using appendChild(),  now it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't really append the created div to the `resultsElement` you can't attach  `eventListener` to it, I change your code a bit.

```js
var resultsElement = document.getElementById("results");
var div = document.createElement("DIV");
div.append("Hey");
div.addEventListener('click', querySomething);
resultsElement.appendChild(div);



function querySomething() {
    alert("hey");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="results">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't realize that just changing the HTML would not carry with it all the properties of the DOM elements including the event. :)